# Can app use android security mechanism (pin code, pattern, password...)?

Tags: android, security

Screen lock have some good security mechanism. (like pin, password, pattern...)
My AP would like to have a similar security mechanism.
Is it possible to invoke screen lock security mechanism?
(so my AP just need to know the result and does not need to handle security by itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do that, for someone reference

```
//put below source code in where you want to launch password UI  
km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);  
if(km.isKeyguardSecure()) {  
    Intent i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);  
    activity.startActivityForResult(i, 1234);  
}  

// call back when password is correct  
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == 1234) {  
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            //do something you want when pass the security  
        }  
    }  
}
```