# Flutter Pin/Password/Pattern Integration

Tags: flutter, localauthentication

I have went through the local_auth package and it works fine, but it does not have an option to authenticate with password or pin. Help appreciated!

```
String _authorized = 'Not Authorized';//Start

Future<Null> _authenticate() async {
    final LocalAuthentication auth = new LocalAuthentication();
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
        authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: false);
        authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(localizedReason: 'Authenticate');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _authorized = authenticated ? 'Authorized' : 'Not Authorized';
    });
}//End
```

So this is the example code and you can use biometric authentication but what about the default Pin/Password authentication that is also present with fingerprint.

Comment: Please put some code.

Comment: I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718948/3123267) for native Android to force the user to reauthenticate. but it seems nobody wrote any plugin for this method...If this is what you seek, I suggest adding a feature request on flutter's GitHub repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For security reason, mobile (iOS/Android) will only authenticate user by biometrics, **not system password/pin**. If you want to let user authenticate by other methods than biometrics, the app itself must store and process (encrypted) credential which is totally separated from **system password/pin**.

You can see this behavior (to use system-biometrics AND app-specific credential) in many bank/financial related app, such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.konylabs.capitalone&hl=en