# How to Prompt User to Enter Pin in Android Lock Screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, lockscreen, unlock

[Android screen lock/ unlock programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723185/android-screen-lock-unlock-programmatically)

and

[How to lock/unlock phone programmatically : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923992/how-to-lock-unlock-phone-programmatically-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and many questions i have searched for answer but i didn't got the exact answer for my usage.

I would like to get a enter credentials or Enter pin page in Lock Screen Default System Lock Screen.
When we say Ok Google the Google will prompt to enter the credentials .

I need the same time. I m asking just to wipe out screen and enter credentials

Give me the answer which would for All android versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the below code to open password/pin/pattern screen and validate user device credentials:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    if (km.isKeyguardSecure()) {
        Intent authIntent = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(getString(R.string.dialog_title_auth), getString(R.string.dialog_msg_auth));
        startActivityForResult(authIntent, INTENT_AUTHENTICATE);
    }
}
```

and also implement onActivityResult's method to get the results in your case is successful or not.

```
// call back when password is correct  
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == INTENT_AUTHENTICATE) {  
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            //do something you want when pass the security  
        }  
    }  
}
```

You can check ref URL from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718948/4360419)

Comment: I m asking about in Lockscreen. You are referring to lockscreen security prompt in my app when it is in open.

Comment: hey @Arsal : How to achieve same thing in Flutter? please help