# How to make BiometricPrompt non-cancelable?

Tags: android, androidx, android-biometric-prompt

I am using `BiometricPrompt` in my application. It works well and shows the dialog when call the `authenticate()` method. But this dialog gets closing when I click outside the dialog. How to prevent it? How to make BiometricPrompt's dialog non-cancelable? Here is no method like `biometricPrompt.setCancelable(false)`.

Comment: seems the feature is not available, i suggest to use custom dialog for same purpose.

Comment: Have you tried `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`?

Comment: @MadLeo From documentation: "In Android 9 and higher, the FingerprintManager API is deprecated. If your bundled and system apps use this API, update them to use BiometricPrompt instead". https://source.android.com/security/biometric

Comment: @MehulSolanki As I see, there is no method available with this name: https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt

Comment: U can handle it in onAuthenticationError with error code BiometricPrompt.ERROR_USER_CANCELED

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You have to use the **version 1.0.0-beta01** or later.

Now it is the **default** behavior:
**Touches outside no longer cancel authentication. Back button cancel authentication still.**

You can see the [changelog:](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135684487)

> Changed behavior to not allow `BiometricPrompt` to be cancelled by a touch event outside the prompt.

You can check also the [rewiew report](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1087531/).
**No new API.**

Comment: FragmentManager is already executing transactions       error after update to 1.0,1

Comment: Hi Gabriele, any chance you know how to implement something like onDismiss or onCancel listener? I wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: I have tried with v1.0.1 and v1.1.0-alpha01. The dialog gets dismissed when I tap outside. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: downvote because the prompt is dismissed when clicking outside the prompt on 1.1.0-rc01

Answer (score 3):

`BiometricPrompt` does not allow that. So you won't be able to make the system-provided biometric prompt non-cancelable. But you can detect whenever user cancels the dialog.

So an option would be, to show again the biometric prompt after user cancel it (which I think would be a bad user experience) or use alternate user authentication:

```
override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
        if (errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED) {
            // User canceled the operation

            // you can either show the dialog again here

            // or use alternate authentication (e.g. a password) - recommended way
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we provide an alternate authentication if the fingerprint fails ? Like an android device pin to retrieve the password from keystore?

Comment: Yes you can. You can open password/pin/pattern screen and validate user device credentials. Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52504424/3955965

Comment: You should probably use setDeviceCredentialAllowed instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder.html#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

check it out

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
        if(it is DialogFragment) {
            it.dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The biometric prompt is not necessarily a dialog depending on the device. For instance, on OnePlus devices, a fullscreen view may be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some devices that still have this issue. An work around will be to get root view and add an overlay view with clickable method set to false.

```
    ViewGroup  viewGroup =  ((ViewGroup) yourActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

    //create your view
    Display display = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    View view = new View(yourActivity);
    view.setId(R.id.overlay_view);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size.x, size.y));
    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(yourActivity, R.color.black));
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //do nothing prevent click under this overlay
    });

    //add your view on top of the screen
    viewGroup.addView(view);

    //call your biometric dialog
    ....

    //on callbacks even if it is error or success call remove view
    viewGroup.removeView(view);
```