# Disable back button in full screen androidx.BiometricPrompt

Tags: androidx, android-biometric-prompt

I am using `BiometricPrompt (androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha01)` as an additional security measure in my app if the user configures to do so. But once this is enabled, I would like this to be non-cancellable (disable back button).

For now, if the user presses back button, BiometricPrompt invokes authenticationFailure callback. Is there a way to achieve this? For now I am re-invoking the BiometricPrompt on authenticationFailure but that's quite hacky.

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475507/how-to-make-biometricprompt-non-cancelable) but that's about the biometric prompt dialog. I am using the full screen version.