# Biometric Issue In Oppo & Realme device

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt

When I touch in other area of  biometric dialog operation get cancelled, It is not happening it other devices so I am not able to find solution, Is anyone has faced same kind of issue , please guide me[image]

Comment: Does this help -[biometric non cancleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475507/how-to-make-biometricprompt-non-cancelable)

Comment: no its not, i real the changelog blogs also but in above case use password button is taking whole area

Comment: You can again open dialog when user gets cancelled by using _errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED_