# Customize the Biometric Prompt for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, multi-factor-authentication, android-biometric-prompt

I have an implementation of the Fingerprint Biometric authentication for Android which works pretty much as described by the documentation. I am trying to remove the close button aka the "setNegativeButtonText" value. This will make the biometric auth a requirement instead of an option.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: "This will make the biometric auth a requirement instead of an option" -- it's always an option, insofar as the user can use system BACK navigation to close that dialog.

Comment: Based on my implementation the back navigation will remove the entire activity as the Biometric Prompt is a pop up.

Answer (score 1):

BiometricPrompt does not allow that. So you won't be able to make the system-provided biometric prompt non-cancelable. But you can detect whenever user cancels the dialog.

Refer below

[How to make BiometricPrompt non-cancelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475507/how-to-make-biometricprompt-non-cancelable)

You can use that cancel button as UsePassword instead with

`setAllowedAuthenticators`

See the release notes here

https://yggr.medium.com/simple-biometric-authentication-in-android-b01be3c40e6f

Comment: Thank you for this. My approach was to use the finish() method to close the Activity if the user clicks close on the onAuthenticationError callback method.