# How to init asking admin's pattern in my code?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing app for Zebra device model MC33. 
I like how internal apps ask to enter admin pattern (password) when I open Settings or others. In my app I have settings activity and I would like to ask user for authorization.
**What I want to have is:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuO0i.jpg

I used class DevicePolicyManager and then call for lock screen. (code is below)

But it turn off the sceen completely (it become black) like the device is switch off. Then I can enter pattern to turn it on.
This is screenshot **what I get after using DevicePolicyManager**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVGrw.jpg

```java
DevicePolicyManager policy = (DevicePolicyManager)             
 getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
policy.lockNow();
```

Such behaviour may be misleading. Do you have idea how to call for proper screen in my app?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504272/how-to-prompt-user-to-enter-pin-in-android-lock-screen

Comment: Thanks @DarrynCampbell, using KeyguardManager helps me and it works as I expected.
But as a result I get screen a little bit different because it is **black** and slightly different: https://imgur.com/gallery/orHgIkf/

Comment: Plus when I run my app the very first time I see screen: https://imgur.com/gallery/BwpAAPI
then I see my new "black" lock screen https://imgur.com/gallery/orHgIkf/. So user have to enter admin pattern twice. 
In the second run all works fine and only "black" lock screen appear.