# Using Android BiometricPrompt or FingerprintManager with password fallback

Tags: xamarin.android, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt

I'm trying to create Android app with secure access to keystore with biometrics.

I'm using this samples:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/FingerprintGuide/
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-m/FingerprintDialog/

Everything works as should but I want to use also screen lock (Password, PIN or pattern) as fallback option. Is it possible to use this fallback with FingerprintManager or new BiometricPrompt? When I'm trying to do this with iOS, there is automatic fallback for this

[image]

Thank You for any help.

Comment: Yes, it could be achieved ,but you can use  simple ways  `KeyguardManager` to acheve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718790/use-system-passcode-for-authentication

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you for answer... but I need to be able to get access to secure key from android keystore with this authentication.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I found out I can use it also with keystore... Thank You!!

Comment: I am glad to hear that, can you share your answer, and make it, it will help others who have similar issue.